# Round BMI to 2 digits in Python

Tags: python, rounding

I'm trying to round a bmi values which is a float value `0.0027041644131963224`. I want my value to look like this `27.00`.

I've tried rounding it like this:

```
bmiCalc = profile.weight / (profile.height*profile.height)
bmi = round(bmiCalc, 2)
```

Comment: ...but what happened? See also [ask]. In general, don't round values. Instead, when displaying them, format them according to your requirements there.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying by 10000?

Comment: If you have to multiply by 10000, you probably used cm instead of m for height.

Comment: @tobias_k the other way around - they probably used cm instead of m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure you forgot to convert the height to meters? Try this:

```
bmiCalc = profile.weight / (profile.height*profile.height / (100**2))
bmi = round(bmiCalc,2)
```

(This would output `27.04` for your example, but you can adjust the decimals in the `round()` function)